# Jquery Mobile Panel Swipe Event and Tabs Swipe Event Inside a page?

Tags: jquery-mobile, tabs, panel, swipe

I have multiple pages inside a single html.
And  I've an external panel that can be swipe in and out (panel can open and close ) in all pages. In one page i have  swipe tabs feature.
Both Panel and  Swipe Tabs functionality are fine now..
My problem is when i come to swipe tabs page,swiping tabs will also pull the panel too, how to adjust these swipe events?, How to detect swipe tabs and  panel swipe events correctly.

Here the [`DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/rahulunni/7d4244v3/30/)  i created, i also need a panel which can also can open and close with swipe events. user can swipe between swipes and swipe to open and close a left panel, panel must be external so it can be available in whole pages.
unfortunately panel not  working in the demo i  don't know whats happening, but working in my project.

Comment: Show us some code and maybe even create a jsFiddle that reproduces the problem? How do you want to distinguish between tab swipes and panel swipes? length of swipe? direction of swipe? position of swipe?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rahulunni/7d4244v3/30/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add the external panel, you can use the regular jQuery document ready:

```
var panel = '<div data-theme="a" data-role="panel" data-display="overlay" id="leftpanel"><ul data-role="listview"><li data-icon="false"><a data-ajax="false" href="index.html">Home</a></li><li data-icon="false"><a data-ajax="false" href="html/examples.html">Examples</a></li><li data-icon="false"><a data-ajax="false" href="html/custom/version.html">Version 1.0.1</a></li></ul></div>';

$(function () {
    $("body").prepend(panel);
    $("[data-role=panel]").panel().enhanceWithin();
});
```

Then you could listen for swipes on the content div to change tabs and on the header div to open/close the panel:

```
$("div[data-role=content]").on("swipeleft", function (event) {
    changeNavTab(true);
});
$("div[data-role=content]").on("swiperight", function (event) {
    changeNavTab(false);
});

// Navigation  Drawer Swipe Listener
$("div[data-role=header]").on("swipeleft swiperight", function (e) {
    // save swipe direction right/left
    var dir = 'prev';
    if (e.type == 'swiperight') {
        dir = 'next';
    }
    if (dir == 'prev') {
        $('#leftpanel').panel('close');

    } else {
        $('#leftpanel').panel('open');

    }
});
```

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/7d4244v3/32/)**

Comment: Thanks !! You really helped me ..!! Is there any way to listen to swipe events by measuring its swipe length or any other way. In your demo i need to swipe header portion to open / close left panel and for tabs need to swipe content area. I need to open/close left panel when i a long swipe and for short swipe to switch between tabs!! is there is  any way to do that.so that user can view and close panel by swiping anywhere in the visible screen.

Comment: @Rahul.S  The jQM swipe event will not do that for you.  You could use the touchstart and touchend events to calculate swipe length and direction or look into other gesture plugins.

Comment: how can i change the above swipe event codes,so that how can i  use it in  nativeDroid2 jquerymobile material  theme tabs  [nativeDroid2 Tabs theme](http://nd2.godesign.ch/examples/extended/tabs.html) . i made a lot of attempt to change but cant fix my need. please help me,

Comment: @Rahul.S, can you update the fiddle and then explain what it is not doing for you?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32051021/jqueymobile-nativedroid2-tabs-swipe). I made a question in stack overflow. please read.