# jQuerymobile nativedroid2 Tabs swipe

Tags: jquery-mobile

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" class="wow fadeIn">
            <a href="#leftpanel" class="ui-btn ui-btn-left"><i class="zmdi zmdi-menu"></i></a>
            <h1 class="wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay='0.4s'>Tabs</h1>

            <ul data-role="nd2tabs" >
                <li data-tab="friends">Friends</li>
                <li data-tab="work" data-tab-active="true">Work</li>
                <li data-tab="holiday">Holiday</li>
                <li data-tab="colors">Colors</li>
            </ul>

        </div>
```

I have nativeDroid2b Tabs jquerymobile material design from [natriveDroid2/Tabs](http://nd2.godesign.ch/examples/extended/tabs.html).

How can I enable swipe feature in this tabs (ie switch between tabs content).

I wrote code for this, but it's not working:

```
$(function () {
            function changeNavTab(left) {
                var $tabs = $("div[data-role=nd2tabs] li ", $("div[data-role=nd2tabs].nd2Tabs-active"));
                var curidx = $tabs.closest("li.nd2Tabs-active").parent().index();
                console.log($tabs);
                var nextidx = 0;
                if (left) {
                    nextidx = (curidx == $tabs.length - 1) ? 0 : curidx + 1;
                } else {
                    nextidx = (curidx == 0) ? $tabs.length - 1 : curidx - 1;
                }
                $tabs.eq(nextidx).click();
            }

            $("div[role=main]").on("swipeleft", function (event) {

                changeNavTab(true);
            });

            $("div[role=main]").on("swiperight", function (event) {

                changeNavTab(false);
            });
        });
```

Kindly help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, use pagecreate instead of the regular jQuery document.ready:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function () {
    $("div[role=main]").on("swipeleft", function (event) {
        changeNavTab(true);
    });

    $("div[role=main]").on("swiperight", function (event) {
        changeNavTab(false);
    });
});
```

Next, in changeNavTab(), the selector should be ul[data-role="nd2tabs"] instead of div[data-role="nd2tabs"]:

```
function changeNavTab(left) {
    var $tabs = $('ul[data-role="nd2tabs"] li');
    console.log($tabs);
    var len = $tabs.length;
    var curidx = 0;
    $tabs.each(function(idx){
        if ($(this).hasClass("nd2Tabs-active")){
            curidx = idx;
        }
    });

    var nextidx = 0;
    if (left) {
        nextidx = (curidx >= len - 1) ? 0 : curidx + 1;
    } else {
        nextidx = (curidx <= 0) ? len - 1 : curidx - 1;
    }
    $tabs.eq(nextidx).click();

}
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/k2htoyt2/)**

Comment: Thank you very much...you really helped me... i don't no how to express my pleasure to you....thank you very much...

Comment: Hi, how to show a loader widget until ajax complete download content & and DOM element update, if u don't mind could u please suggest me a better  practice to do so with example. I already spent many days to search & implement the loader widget but can't fulfill my need.

Comment: Thank you , Thank you so much